# Animating a PNG file in flash CPU

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a PNG file 1024 x 768. On top of that I have other smaller PNG files that "slide in" (only moving along the x and y) via an ENTER_FRAME handler?

I was just wondering, do animating PNGS require more CPU than say, basic vector shapes? Is there anything I could do to optimize my animation?

It's literally like:

```
private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
  myPng.x += speed; // and so on
}
```

Also, if I place the PNG inside of a MovieClip, should I set the MovieClip "cacheAsBitmap" to true or is that implied if I put a PNG file in it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU usage is pretty dependent on the complexity of the vector. A Simple vector will likely animate faster than a large bitmap, but a complex vector will animate much much slower - unless cacheAsBitmap is true for that complex vector.  You're PNG's are already bitmaps so cacheAsBitmap is irrelevant to them.

You're best bet for easy optimization would be to ensure you're using GPU acceleration if possible.  Even better should you require more performance, would be to utilize flash player 11's native 3d support.  Even if not doing actual 3D, you can use a 2D framework like starling (http://gamua.com/starling/) that still taps into that 3D support, giving you much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the opposite. Consider :

- **PNG / Bitmap Image** as a chunk of data to be represented on the screen.
- **Vector Image** as a formula for generating a chunk of data to be represented on the screen.

Now think what you want to do. You want to move the image across, with absolutely no change in the chunk of data. The Obvious answer would be PNG.

Now regarding optimization. I believe you have very less room for optimization, in this task unless you consider [blitting and caching](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html) the results.

Blitting & caching a movieclip is simply reading the bitmap representation (the chunk of data) *from memory* and re-drawing it, reducing the overhead of reading the PNG. But unless you really have some performance issues with your current approach, I wouldn't consider taking the trouble.